# saving instance of the class for restoring activity

Tags: android, destroy

I have a 3rd party library(with source code only - so i can do modification) which i can create the singleton instance of the class. I created the instance of that class in the initial screen activity and i am navigating to 3rd screen. Android clears the initial screen activity and corresponding data objects while the user is away from the 3rd screen. Even though its singleton class, the data inside class not retaining after destroying. I want to store/restore that instance of that class along with `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` to avoid after destroying the activities in the background. i tried `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`, it is giving compilation error as deprecated. And i tried `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance()`, it is not working as we expected. Please help me to get rid of this issue.

Comment: And where is the problem with `onSaveInstanceState`?

Comment: Avoid singleton activities. Use SharedPreferences for simple persistent storage